# How to get call is accepted status in outbond twilio call in twilio voice js sdk?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am making a web application where I need to call customers, Everything is working fine,
but I need the call status when the customer receives the call or rejects the call from their phone. below is the ts code, where i am trying to get status of call but only i am getting accept and close status , where i can get call is accepted or rejected status

```
       ngOnInit(): void {
       this.patientName = this.data.patientName;
    this.phoneNumber = this.data.patientPhoneNumber;
    this.patientId = this.data.id;
    let self = this;
    
    this.authService.getRequest('cutsomer/api/gettoken', null).subscribe((data) => {
        try {
            this.device = Twilio.Device.setup(data['data'], {
                debug: false,
                closeProtection: true
            });
            this.setupHandlers(this.device);
            setTimeout(function () {
                this.iserror = false;
                self.callCustomer();
            }, 500);
        } catch (err) {
    this.modalService.dismissAll();
    if (err.error && err.error.message) {
      this.toastr.error(err.error.message);
    }
        }
    });
      }
     setupHandlers(device) {
    let self = this;

    device.on('ready', (_device) => {
    });

    device.on('error', (error) => {
     if (error.error.message) {
    this.toastr.error(error.error.message);
      }
     this.modalService.dismissAll();
    });
    device.on('connect', (connection) => {
        console.log(connection);
        if ('patientPhoneNumber' in connection.message) {
            this.callStartTime = new Date();
        }
        console.log(connection.status);
        console.log('getcallstatus'+  connection._status);
        
    });

    device.on('disconnect', (connection) => {
        console.log('endcall'+  connection._status);
        this.dialogRef.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
            self.callEndTime = new Date();
            //self.addMessageCenterData();
            let formData = {
                'status' : 'COMPLETED',
                'voiceCallLogId' : self.voiceCallLogId,
                'callEndTime' : self.callEndTime,
                'callSid': connection.parameters.CallSid
            }
            self.updateCallStatus(formData);                
            this.timerRunning = false; 
            
            this.device.disconnectAll();
            self.modalService.dismissAll();
        }, 500);
            });
       device.on('hangup', (connection) => {
        this.callEndTime = new Date();
        });
        }
```